# svn tree structure advise

Tags: svn, version-control

I have inherited a big project which isn't under any version control.
The project is big: 
around: 9000 files & 600 directories, so We should keep the structure even if it isn't organized the svn way.

The structure is as follows:

-\Src

    -\Common

     -\Help

     -\Lib

    **-\TheProject

     -main.pas

     -more-files.pas

              -\Engine.A

              -\Engine.B

              -\Engine.C**

              -\Common

              -\Utils

   -\SomeMore

   -\SomeMore

For some customers we use Engine.A, for others Engine.B, etc...
Before we do any progress we rename 'Engine.A' to 'Engine' --> develope --> compile -->rename back to Engine.A. Same for all other engines folders.

Any suggestion how to work that out? 
Please note: Each engine only change about 10% of the files, so branch will be a lot of work on.

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Why you dont want to use git (with submodules for your engines)?

Comment: @v2p: well...whats the pros? Sorry, I am not familiar with git

Comment: I am not a big profy. But try to use git - its not hard to learn it, but after that you can do with your code whatever you want. 

Problems with svn-branching will be forgotten like a bad dream.

See: http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the official [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

The chapters about branches and merging should be interesting and give some guidance.

Comment: Branching doesn't solve my problem...Or am I missing something?

Comment: The chapter branching and merging covers both. Branching and merging. I'm not sure if you should do something like the vendor branches described in there. If you use branches then you could roll out updates after you improved your engine. I think its likely that you have different versions of your engine and want to move over new features to the other customers as well.